# Icon specified in the Info.plist CFBundleIconFile does not have an extension

Tags: iphone

when i want to send my app to itunesconnect from applicationloader occur below error how to solve it ?

Icon specified in the Info.plist CFBundleIconFile does not have an extension

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you added the icon file (CFBundleIconFile) you have to save it with the .png at the end of it. So if it was called Filename it needs to be Filename.png in your info plist.